# Temporary table or Truncate fix table?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 5 fields obtained form two tables to insert into another table. Is it more efficient to do it with temporary table or with a fix table and truncate it each time I use it ?

If a temporary is more effective how to create within in c# a temporary table. Because this sql is not working ?

```
    public static void CreateTempProd()
    {
        int result;
        string sqlstr = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ##tmptbl (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, dt DATETIME NOT NULL, qty int11 NOT NULL, rest int11 NOT NULL, nom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY id, ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8)";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstr,conn);
        MySqlTransaction trans;
        conn.Open();
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return;
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is a bit off;

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ##tmptbl (           -- ## needs quoting
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    qty int11 NOT NULL,                     -- int11 should be int(11)
    rest int11 NOT NULL,                    -- int11 should be int(11)
    nom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL NOT NULL       -- double NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY id,                         -- id needs braces
    ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8      -- should go outside the table braces
)
```

That is, it should be something like...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `##tmptbl` (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dt DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  qty int(11) NOT NULL, 
  rest int(11) NOT NULL, 
  nom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8
```

A good idea is to just try running your exact query at the mysql command prompt, that would have caught this error and allowed you to fix it.

Comment: It's works perfectly. Thanks a lot. How about the effectivity between temporary table and fix table to truncate each time ? Which is the the best solution ?

Comment: @IsmailGunes Of the two I'd use a temporary (session local) table, since it won't have a problem if multiple queries are going on at once. A table that is used in multiple queries at once and being truncated by one session while accessed by another could cause big problems.